# For loop in swift confused

Tags: swift

So swift changed their for loop you can't do

```
for (i = 0; i <10; i++){
    //do some stuff
}
```

You can only do

```
for i in 0...100 {
   //do some stuff
}
```

My question is where do `i` put the `i = i + 1?` I tried putting it in the `for` function but it doesn't work.

Comment: you don't need to consider that.

Comment: That loop already increments `i` from 0 to 100. Just use `i` inside the loop and don't try to do `i = i + 1`.

Answer (score 5):

You use stride to create a range if you need an increment of something other than one:

```
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: 10, by: 2) {
        print (i) // 0,2,4,6,8
    }

    for i in stride(from: 0, through: 10, by: 2) {
        print (i) // 0,2,4,6,8,10
    }

    for i in stride(from: 0, through: 10, by: 2).reversed() {
        print (i) // 10,8,6,4,2,0
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work in playground.. i get an error and it doesn't read stride..

Comment: @DarrenZou make sure you import UIKit

Comment: yeah it is imported by default.

Comment: @DarrenZou Xcode/Swift version ? Swift 2 syntax is `for i in 0.stride(to: 10, by: 2)`

Comment: Something is wrong with your playground.  Stride is part of the Swift 3.0 standard library.  If you are importing Foundation (UIKit imports Foundation) and using Swift 3 / Xcode 8 you should see it.  It also works in the IBM REPL here: https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl

Comment: yeah, updated my swift and got it to work. also how to do add values to a array? for example if i have [1,2,3,4,5] and i want to add 2 to all values..

Answer (score 0):

`for` loop in Swift is like `foreach` in other languages. You can think of every `for` loop as:

```
foreach i in (a sequence of values) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Different constructs are provided to help you build this sequence quickly and succintly in code:

```
0..<n                               // a sequence from 0 to (n-1)
0...n                               // a sequence from 0 to n
stride(from: 0, to: n: by: 3)       // a sequence from 0 to n-1, jumping 3 values at a time
stride(from: n, to: 0, by: -1)      // a sequence from n down to 1
stride(from: n, through: 0, by -1)  // a sequence from n down to 0
```